# React Hook Form isSubmitSuccessful returning false on first submission

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, next.js, react-hook-form

I am creating a form for my website using [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/) with [EmailJS](https://www.emailjs.com/). I'm accessing the ["isSubmitSuccessful" property](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/formstate) to dynamically show a dialog popup (using the [Headless UI dialog component](https://headlessui.com/react/dialog)). When I try to send the form, on the first attempt, isSubmitSuccessful returns false even if the form is valid. The EmailJS sendForm function does not throw an error and returns successfully. Note: I am also using reCAPTCHA v2 which may be causing problems.

When I purposely fail the submission by leaving the reCAPTCHA checkbox empty, the form will send successfully on the second attempt. However, the form submission continuously fails on the first try. I also tried to prevent default behavior (e.preventDefault) and this did not fix it.

I have not been able to find much info on this, if anyone has advice I appreciate it.

Here is my code (note that I am using Next.js 13):

```
"use client";

import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import emailjs from "@emailjs/browser";
import styles from "./Contact.module.css";
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";
import DialogPopup from "../shared/Dialog/Dialog";

function ContactForm() {
  const [dialogIsOpen, setDialogIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const form = useRef();
  const recaptchaRef = useRef(null);

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: { isSubmitSuccessful },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      user_name: "",
      user_email: "",
      message: "",
    },
  });

  const openDialog = () => {
    setDialogIsOpen(true);
  };

  const closeDialog = () => {
    reset();
    recaptchaRef.current.reset();
    setDialogIsOpen(false);
  };

  const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        "contact_service",
        "contact_form",
        form.current,
        // Removed key for security
      )
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log("isSubmitSuccessful", isSubmitSuccessful);
          console.log("SUCCESS!");
          console.log(result.text);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log("isSubmitSuccessful", isSubmitSuccessful);
          console.log("FAILED...");
          console.log(error.text);
          alert("Please verify that you are a human.");
        }
      );
    if (isSubmitSuccessful) {
      openDialog();
    }
  };

  return (
    <form
      className={styles["contact-form"]}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
      ref={form}
    >
      <input
        className={styles["contact-form-field"]}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Name"
        name="user_name"
        {...register("user_name", { required: true, maxLength: 120 })}
      />
      <input
        className={styles["contact-form-field"]}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Email"
        name="user_email"
        {...register("user_email", { required: true, pattern: /^\S+@\S+$/i })}
      />
      <textarea
        className={styles["contact-form-field"]}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Additional Information"
        name="message"
        {...register("message", {
          required: false,
          maxLength: 250,
        })}
      />

      <ReCAPTCHA
        sitekey={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_KEY}
        ref={recaptchaRef}
      />
      <input className={styles.submit} type="submit" value="Send" />

      <DialogPopup
        title="Message Sent!"
        description="Thank you for your inquiry"
        buttonText="Finish"
        isOpen={dialogIsOpen}
        closeDialog={closeDialog}
      />
    </form>
  );
}

export default ContactForm;
```

**Edit:**

After reading through the RHF docs and running some tests, it seems to be related to using EmailJS with RHF. I don't think RHF recognizes the EmailJS sendForm method, so when handleSubmit calls this, it doesn't pass "isSubmitSuccessful." I moved the openDialog() to be called when sendForm is successful. This appears to be working.